# Is There a Generalized Binet-Style Formula for Tribonacci Sequences with Arbitrary Initial Values?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

A Tribonacci Sequence is a list of numbers where the $n$th entry in the list $T(n)$ is the sum of the previous three entries $T(n - 1)$, $T(n - 2)$, and $T(n - 3)$. The function $T(n)$ can be written as

$$T(n) = \frac{p^n}{(p - q) (p - r)} + \frac{q^n}{(q - p) (q - r)} + \frac{r^n}{(r - p) (r - q)}$$

Or equivalently

$$T(n) = -\frac{(q - r) p^n + (r - p) q^n + (p - q) r^n}{(p - q) (r - p) (q - r)}$$

Where

$$p = \frac{1}{6} \left(2 + 2 \sqrt[3]{19 + \sqrt{297}} + 2 \sqrt[3]{19 - \sqrt{297}}\right)$$
$$q = \frac{1}{6} \left(2 + i \left(i - \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{19 + \sqrt{297}} + i \left(i + \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{19 - \sqrt{297}}\right)$$
$$r = \frac{1}{6} \left(2 + i \left(i + \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{19 + \sqrt{297}} + i \left(i - \sqrt{3}\right) \sqrt[3]{19 - \sqrt{297}}\right)$$

As written, these functions give the Tribonacci sequence starting with the initial values $T(0) = 0$, $T(1) = 0$, and $T(2) = 1$. However, a Tribonacci sequence can be defined using any three initial values.

With the famous Fibonacci sequence, Binet's formula $F(n) = \frac{φ^n - ψ^n}{φ - ψ}$, which gives the sequence starting with $F(0) = 0$ and $F(1) = 1$, can be modified to use arbitrary initial values by adding $U = F_1 - F_0 ψ$ and $V = F_1 - F_0 φ$ to get the expression $F(n) = \frac{U φ^n - V ψ^n}{φ - ψ}$, which gives the sequence starting with $F(0) = F_0$ and $F(1) = F_1$.

I want to have an analogous modification for the Tribonacci Binet-style function that lets it generate Tribonacci sequences with arbitrary initial values, for example by defining some values $U$, $V$, and $W$ and adding them to the Tribonacci function the same way $U$ and $V$ are added to the Fibonacci function. However, my attempts to figure this out on my own have been unsuccessful. How should I go about finding this modified function?

Comment: It's still a sum of exponentials $p^n, q^n, r^n$, just the coefficients are different, and you can solve for those coefficients in terms of the initial conditions.

Comment: The tag "recurrence relations" will index many similar questions. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_recurrence_with_constant_coefficients for some information on recurrences of the type you are interested in.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I've tried to figure out how to solve for the coefficients in terms of the initial conditions, but I'm stuck. Can you explain how to go about doing that?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Never mind, I made a typo early on in the process that I completely missed until now that was turning the results into nonsense. I got it working.